# Como as "if" or "as"

Tags: vocabulario, abreviaturas

What is best match for word "como" in the phrase below? I suppose it is used as common sense - "as", but can it be translated as "if", making it conditional? The phrase origin is not modern, it's from ancient text dated 1674.

> Y como este Autor siga en los Puntos aqui citados la Doctrina, como la
> confiessa en lo demás que escriue, puede seruirse V.A. de darle la
> licencia que pide.

Another question what is "V.A." stands for? I suppose V. is "Vuestra", like "Vuestra merced" or "Vuestra Majestad", but what can be A. ?

Comment: No, it cannot be if, that's for sure. It's **as**.

Answer (score 2):

V. A. I guess is *Vuestra Alteza*

> Y como este Autor siga en los Puntos aquí citados la Doctrina de D. Luis Pacheco De Narbaez, como la confiesa en lo demás que escribe, puede servirse Vuestra Alteza de darle la licencia que pide.

I personally don't see any conditional, it's clearly "as".

From what I understood from the writing, he is describing his mastery of sword use, so each previous and subsequent written detail (lo demás que escribe) serves as an endorsement to request the license to *Vuesa Alteza* the King

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. The context below the phrase is that is conclusion from peer review ("Censura") on famous La Verdadera Destreza treatise by Don Francisco Antonio de Ettenhard. Reviewer (Maestro Mayor de la Destreza Juan Caro de Montenegro) found 15 issues ("Puntos") that deviate from la Doctrina de Pacheco, but still grants the permission to print the treatise. So the question is that permission conditional, after all these issues corrected or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Antecedentes**

El censor Juan Caro de Montenegro, señala una serie de puntos de la obra de D. Francisco Antonio Ettenhard que son contrarios a la doctrina de Don Luis Pacheco Narbaez, al cual consideraba maestro el propio D. Francisco Antonio y que el mismo censor, en cierto sentido, lo estima como apóstata. Quiere este censor, Juan Caro, que D. Francisco Antonio, confiese antes de imprimir. Posteriormente D. Francisco Antonio Ettenhard hará sus alegaciones para defenderse.

---

**Actualmente es destacable que utilizaríamos preferentemente el** "**si**" **+ el verbo en Presente Indicativo /o Pretérito Imperfecto del Subjuntivo.**

**En un español moderno diríamos**; "Y si este Autor rectifica (o rectificara), los Puntos aquí citados (se refiere a las páginas anteriores) contrarios a la Doctrina de Don Luis Pacheco Narbaez, tal y como lo defiende en lo demás que escribe, puede Vuestra Alteza (V.A) otorgarle la licencia que pide.

---

Hoy en día no utilizaríamos el imperativo o el presente de subjuntivo del verbo "seguir", para expresar la frase, aunque en la antigüedad si seria correcto y por tanto el primer "como" que aparece en la frase seria el adecuado.

---

> Y como este Autor **siga** en los Puntos aqui citados la Doctrina **de Don
> Luis Pacheco Narbaez**, como la confiessa en lo demás que escriue, puede
> seruirse V.A. de darle la licencia que pide. Madrid a diez y ocho de
> Agosto de mil seiscientos sesenta y cuatro.

[image]

*Compendio de los fundamentos de la verdadera destreza y filosofia de las armas. Antonio Ettenhard*

---

The censor Juan Caro de Montenegro points out a series of points in the work of Mr. Francisco Antonio Ettenhard that are contrary to the doctrine of Mr. Luis Pacheco Narbaez, whom Mr. Francisco Antonio himself considered a master and that the same censor, in In a certain sense, he regards him as an apostate. This censor, Juan Caro, wants D. Francisco Antonio to confess before printing. Subsequently, D. Francisco Antonio Ettenhard will make his allegations to defend himself.

**Currently it is noteworthy that we would preferentially use the "si" + the verb in the Present Indicative / or the Preterite Imperfect of the Subjunctive.**

**In modern Spanish we would say**; "And if this Author rectifies (rectifica o rectificara), the Points cited here (referring to the previous pages) contrary to the Doctrine of Don Luis Pacheco Narbaez, as defended in the rest that he writes, Your Highness (V.A) can grant you the license you ask for.

---

Today we would not use the imperative or the present subjunctive of the verb "to follow" to express the sentence, although in ancient times it would be correct and therefore the first "como" that appears in the sentence would be appropriate.

---

**Significado de V.A.** / Meaning of V.A.

**V.A.** = **V**uestra **A**lteza

Comment: Una respuesta que repite la anterior añadiendo el comentario del OP.

Comment: Background is not correct, Ettenhard wasn't Pacheco student (Pacheco died before Ettenhard born) and didn't manifest himself to be an apostate of Pacheco's doctrina.

Comment: Repetir respuestas sin una contribución significativa está mal visto, realmente debería considerar simplemente mejorar otra respuesta en lugar de copiar la anterior y llamarla propia.

Comment: This is not if in translation; it's **as** both times.

Comment: RESPUESTA DEL AUTOR A LA CENSURA DE IVAN  CARO DE MONTENEGRO...Y antes de entrar a manifestar, no à satisfacer, los Puntos que como Apostata de la Doctrina de Don Luis Pacheco Naruaez, mi unico Maestro, quiere este censor que confiese...pag. 278

Comment: .https://books.google.es/books?id=bdSlrZKde7AC&pg=PP12&lpg=PP12&dq=Compendio+de+los+fundamentos+de+la+verdadera+destreza+y+filosofia+de+las+armas+Escrito+por+Antonio+Ettenhard&source=bl&ots=_gE5gvrqJq&sig=ACfU3U20TKQqhkECsR7pjteqJTHEOXt5Rw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidk8bX3sH5AhUOUhoKHeDeDGkQ6AF6BAgPEAM#v=onepage&q=Compendio%20de%20los%20fundamentos%20de%20la%20verdadera%20destreza%20y%20filosofia%20de%20las%20armas%20Escrito%20por%20Antonio%20Ettenhard&f=false pag. 278

Comment: como apostata is clearly as, not if.

Comment: @Lambie, la frase esta bien construida en español antiguo, y el segundo "como", que aparece es correcto. Solo indico que hoy en día no utilizaríamos el imperativo o el presente de subjuntivo para expresar o construir la primera parte de la frase y por tanto el primer "como", hoy en día, sonaría mejor con "si" + el verbo en presente de indicativo o pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo. En ningún momento hago referencia al segundo "como", que como digo es correcto y que la frase en español antiguo es igualmente correcta. Sea solo un mal entendido.

Comment: – *el primer "como", hoy en día, sonaría mejor con "si"* – es una suposición arbitraria que incluso cambiaría totalmente el sentido de la frase.

Comment: @Danielillo esta respuesta no repite la otra respuesta, más bien da la opinion **contraria** a la otra respuesta: que la frase sí es condicional. La verdad es que yo también lo entiendo como condicional: la licencia se da solo si el autor corrige esos puntos. Si esos puntos no siguen la doctrina, no tiene sentido decir "como estos puntos siguen la doctrina, le damos la licencia". En cualquier caso, esta respuesta no es una copia.

Comment: @Danielillo además, la estructura "como + presente de subjuntivo" incluso ahora se usa como condicional, por ejemplo: "Como llegues tarde, verás lo que pasa".

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaración, tiene sentido. Aunque me gustaría destacar que como la pregunta consta de dos partes, tampoco estaría demás hacer notar los puntos coincidentes. Por ejemplo –V. A. es Vuestra Alteza *tal como mencionan en la respuesta anterior* – Algo que no cuesta absolutamente nada y que, siendo un antiguo usuario de varios sitios dentro de SE, veo habitualmente y lo comparto, tanto por decencia como por respeto a quien ofrece parte de su tiempo y esfuerzo en elaborar una respuesta.

Comment: @Danielillo cuando me puse a editar la pregunta aún no había respondido nadie y  tiempo después de buscar imágenes y textos apropiados, cuando por fin la acabe, simplemente la subí sin reparar en que alguien, en este caso tu, ya la había contestado. Por supuesto no fue intencionado, de lo contrarío obviamente hubiera hecho referencia a tu contestación. Gracias a ti.

Comment: Entendido, en todo caso, para evitar todo tipo de dudas, también tienes la opción de editar la respuesta. Ante un caso tan evidente a mi entender, solo seguí los pasos detallados en [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103839/391011), quizás también te sea útil.